# Rotating UIView with AVCaptureVideoPreviewLayer as a sublayer

Tags: swift, xcode, uiview, avfoundation, swift4

I want to rotate a UIVIew with a AVCaptureVideoPreviewLayer as a sublayer.

In the UIView appears two buttons (ones rotate the video preview layer to the left and the other to the right) and when the user taps one of them, rotes the preview layer 1 degree each time.

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
   ...
   videoPreviewLayer = AVCaptureVideoPreviewLayer(session: captureSession!)
   videoPreviewLayer?.frame = self.view.bounds
   videoPreviewLayer?.videoGravity = AVLayerVideoGravity.resizeAspectFill
   previewView.layer.addSublayer(videoPreviewLayer!)
}


@objc func rotateRight() {
    degrees += 1

    // 1st possibility - Scale the UIView that contains the previewLayer for 2x
    /*
    previewView.transform = CGAffineTransform(scaleX: 2, y: 2)
    previewView.transform = CGAffineTransform(rotationAngle: (CGFloat(degrees / 180.0 * .pi)))
    previewView.transform = CGAffineTransform.identity
    */

    // 2nd possibility - Make bigger the previewLayer so when it's rotate doesn't appear the background color of the UIView
    /*
    videoPreviewLayer?.frame = CGRect(x: -200, y: -200, width: 800, height: 1200)
    videoPreviewLayer?.position = CGPoint(x: view.bounds.midX, y: view.bounds.midY)
    videoPreviewLayer?.transform = CATransform3DMakeRotation(CGFloat(degrees / 180.0 * .pi), 0.0, 0.0, 1.0)
    */

    // 3rd possibility
    /*
    videoPreviewLayer?.frame = CGRect(x: -200, y: -200, width: 800, height: 1200)
    videoPreviewLayer?.position = CGPoint(x: view.bounds.width * 0.5, y: view.bounds.width * 0.5)
    videoPreviewLayer?.transform = CATransform3DMakeRotation(CGFloat(degrees / 180.0 * .pi), 0.0, 0.0, 1.0)
    */

    // 4th possibility
    UIView.animate(withDuration: 1, animations: {
        self.previewView.contentMode = UIViewContentMode.scaleToFill
        self.previewView.transform = CGAffineTransform(rotationAngle: CGFloat(self.degrees))
    })
}
```

**FINAL RESULT REQUIRED**
[Final result required](https://drive.google.com/open?id=1Hs6tvLQPfXmGXKjFxj6IeMpeM0RMdVqg)

**ACTUAL RESULT**

I have try 4 different ways to create this rotation, but all of them had failed. 
I hope that all this code and its result doesn't make you be more confusing.

*Result of 2nd possibility code*
[link](https://drive.google.com/open?id=1Hs6tvLQPfXmGXKjFxj6IeMpeM0RMdVqg)

*Result of 3rd possibility code*
[link](https://drive.google.com/open?id=1GcqQyyHh-XUAwVWcjIWB1E1k180NJNZ5)

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried

```
if let videoPreviewLayerConnection = videoPreviewLayer.connection {
    videoPreviewLayerConnection.videoOrientation = desiredOrientation
}
```